# Sign Problem When Calculating the Potential of an Infinite Line Charge

Tags: electric-fields, potential, integration

Similar questions have been asked before in the forum regarding the sign problems when integrating the electric field, but they do not fully clarify the problem for me, so I just want to ask for some further clarification.

Suppose we have a positively infinite line charged ($\lambda$ is the linear charge density), which should have an electric field of $$\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r}$$
To find the potential of a point with a distance of $a$ to the linear charge, I set an arbitrary point with a distance of $b$ to the linear charge to have a zero potential ($a<b$). Performing the integration, I got $${-\int_b^a \overrightarrow Ed\overrightarrow l}={-\int_b^a \frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r} (-dr)}={-\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0}{ln \frac{b}{a}}}$$

I use $-dr$ because the integration path is in the opposite direction to the electric field. However, the answer is definitely incorrect due to the sign issue. Do I have any conceptual mistakes or that is just a calculation mistake (I just learnt calculus last year and started physics this year, so I might make some silly mistakes)?

Comment: Hi Farcher, thank you for sharing that link with me. However, it does not really clarify the thing for me. In its example of a point charge, we set dl as negative dr and get the correct answer. However, in the case of linear charge, doing so seems to yield the wrong answer.

Comment: @ZZZ Farcher's link includes a (correct) derivation where $d\vec{l} = + dr \hat{r}$ (with the positive sign) and gets the correct result.  If you're referring to a derivation that was done in your own class, you might compare it to Farcher's derivation and see where it differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest to rewrite your integral as
$$
-\int_b^a \vec E\cdot d\vec \ell = + \int_a^b \vec E\cdot d\vec \ell
$$
with the change in sign coming from the interchange in the limit.  Since $a<b$, the path from $a$ to $b$ now contains positive increments so
$\vec E\cdot d\vec \ell=+E dr$.

There are discussions of how to pick the sign of $d\vec \ell$ in various textbooks (*v.g.* Halliday-Resnick-Walker I think) but they all seem obscure to me, where the interchange of the limit so the increment is positive is IMO much more natural.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does that mean that if we simply exchange the upper bound and lower bound (by reversing the sign before the integral), we will be able to change the sign of dl? But will that mean that both negative and positive answers make sense?

Comment: interchanging the bounds of the integral does not change the sign of $d\vec \ell$, but it clarifies the sign to be chosen.  $\vec E\cdot d\vec\ell$ is a scalar so if you change the limits of integration it does not change the value of the scalar.  What changing the limit does it allow you to go from small $r$ to large $r$, so that $d\vec \ell$ unambiguously points in the $\hat r$ direction.

Comment: So basically here dl is always radically outward, regardless of the bounds of the integral?

Comment: that's one way of thinking about it I suppose but that's not how I think about it.  I reorganize the limits so the $d\ell$ is clearly always outward.  There are discussions on how $d\ell$ can be inward, but that the sign of $d\ell$ is already accounted for in some ways.  (I would have to search for the exact source where this is discussed.). Honestly this kind of argument confuses me.  In the end, if you arrange the limits so the path is in the direction of increasing $r$'s, then you get the math right and the physics makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote, *In its example of a point charge, we set dl as negative dr and get the correct answer* but I cannot comment as I have not seen the derivation.

Let me try and explain your error.

The electric field from the line charge is $\dfrac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r}\,\hat r$ ie radially outwards from the line charge.

If the position of a unit positve changes by $d\vec r=dr\,\hat r$ then the work done by the electric field on the change is $\dfrac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r}\,\hat r \cdot dr\,\hat r = \dfrac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \cdot dr$.

From the definition of potential the change in the potential is $dV = - \dfrac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \cdot dr$.

Note that if $dr$ is positive (unit charge further from line charge) the potential drops and if $dr$ is negative (unit charge closer to line charge) then the potential increases.

The limits of integration will determine whether $r$ is increasing or decreasing and hence whether $dr$ is positive of $dr$ is negative.

Now let's move the unit charge from $r=b$ to $r=a$ with no mention of the relative magnitudes of $a$ and $b$.

$\displaystyle \int_{V(b)}^{V(a)} dV = \int_b^a- \dfrac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0 r} \cdot dr\Rightarrow V(a)-V(b) = \frac{\lambda}{2 \pi \epsilon_0}{\ln \frac{b}{a}}$

Check - If $b>a$ then $V(a)>V(b)$ and if $b<a$ then $V(a)<V(b)$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that certainly helps! Just a follow-up question: if you exchange the limits of the integral (and change the sign before the integral), will the sign of dr change? If that is the case, will that mean that both positive and negative answers will be acceptable (which is clearly not)?

Comment: The formula I derived for the change in potential works for all changes from b to a. No change of sign is required.

Comment: So in this situation, dl is simply radically outward? Can I make such an assumption for similar questions?

Comment: $d\vec \ell = dr\,\hat r$ where $dr$ is the **component** (could be positive or negative) of $d\vec \ell$ in the $\hat r$ direction. The sign is determined (automatically) when the limits of integration are added.